Unable to use Scaffold widget in flutter with the following errors: required parameter 'home' must be provided
I'm using android studio 2022 to build a flutter app, but when I using Scaffold it show that 'home' should be provided but there is no doc on flutter document page show that Scaffold widget has that parameter. The following errors:
required parameter 'home' must be provided,

and some similar errors like above.
class MyFirstApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFirstApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomeScreen({super.key});

      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => HomeState();
}
  
class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold( //the error shown here: required parameter 'home' must be provided
             body: const Text("Hello world")
          )
      }
}

I'm using flutter 3.24 and dart 3.5

Are you mixing up MaterialApp and Scaffold? It's MaterialApp that needs home

@Ivo The error message indicates that the 'Scaffold' widget  must have 'home' parameter provided, you can check my code above.

Do you maybe have some package imported that has a different Scaffold? Check if your imports are right

@Ivo  I import it correctly from flutter/material.dart, and I did not import other packages.

The problem is caused by dart-tool folder with generated files. I used the flutter_localization package on my project but when I clone it from github in another devices and it didn't have dart-tool with generated files so dart-tool didn't work properly. I just setup and configure again and it solved! Thanks.

Check the comment. Under the material widget, home is missing. Maybe, in your code, this error only occurred when you skipped the home parameter.
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp( 
              home: MyHomePage(),  // Ensure you provide the 'home' parameter here
            );
        }
    }


Thanks, but the error message indicates that  Scaffold widget need home parameter, not MaterialApp widget, you can check my code above
